# Dynamic Programming of a Knapsack-like problem

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

I need a bit of help coming up with a bottom-up approach to a Knapsack-like problem.

Problem:
Basically, you have some items, each item has a value and a weight and you want to pick the items that have the add up to the least weight but the sum of values get you to a certain value that is provided.
Let's say we have a 2d array with our weights and values.
The weights and values are nonnegative.
ex:
|index| Weights  | Values |
|-----| -------- | ------ |
|1    |    3     |   15   |
|2    |    29    |   5    |
|3    |    12    |   1    |
|4    |    99    |   2    |
|5    |    12    |   9    |
|6    |    0     |   40   |

and we also have a threshold for the values that we need to get to or go above(instead of a limit in Knapsack).

So we want to pick the items that have the least weight but get us to or above the threshold.
So the threshold for the example above is 64. and we can choose the items 1,2,5,6 that gives us a weight of 44 and a value of 69 that is above the threshold.
I hope the problem is clear, if not I can provide more examples later.
Here is a formula for what we want:

[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vx6wg.png)

My solution till now:
I'm working to build a dynamic table using a bottom-up approach. This is the pig picture code that I have for building the part that builds the table:

```html
// arr: 2D array that holds the weigth and values (starting from index 0)
// Values: the second column of the array
// Weights: the first column of the array
// n = Number of distinct items
// W = the threshold
// m: table that I store the values in



for j from 0 to W do:
m[0, j] := INF

for i from 1 to n do:
for j from 0 to W do:
if arr[i-1,1] > j then:
m[i, j] := m[i-1, j]
else:
m[i, j] := min(m[i-1, j], m[i-1, j-arr[i-1,1]] + arr[i-1,0])
return m[n,W]
```

Basically, I'm getting subtracting the value from the threshold and finding the minimum amount(i.e the minimum weight possible to get there).
However, this isn't giving me the correct table in a lot of tests and I can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

I'm kind of stuck, any hint or reference to correctly build the table would be really appreciated.

Comment: is this for an ongoing exam?

Comment: No, it's part of a CS project. But I'm not asking for a code, I'm just asking for some hits or a resource that I could read.

Comment: You can take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem. Note that in the problem presented, the weight of adding one coin is always 1

Answer (score 0):

Your solution can't get values above the threshold. Just calculate the same dynamic programming up to `W+(max value in array)` and for answer find minimum within `m[n, W+e]` for `e >= 0` and `W+e` is within array bounds.